# ASP.NET Core Web API on localhost does not pass data to Angular app served on localhost

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I built a simple proof of concept ASP.NET Core Web API project with "minimal APIs". It serves out data from a database and worked in Swagger as well as just calling the url, like http://localhost:5112/qnas. I built an Angular app to consume the data from the api and show the results to the user, and it ran on http://localhost:4200.

There was no error on the Angular side in my service:

```
fetchQuestions(): Observable<Question[]> {
    return this.http.get<Question[]>(this.URLForQNAs);
}
```

There was no message in component typescript where it attempts to process the resulting observable:

```
fetchQuestions(): void {
    this.fds.fetchQuestions().subscribe(q => { this.messageService.add('In Questions...'); this.aQuestions = q; this.messageService.add('Got Questions: ' + q.length); });
}
```

The ASP.NET Core Web API code is pretty much straight out of the box and I added a mapget to serve the records:

```
app.MapGet("/qnas", () => {
    return new QuestionController().GetQNAs();
}).WithName("GetQNAs");
```

The Angular app worked when I dummied the data in the app or when I tried to consume data from other Web APIs on the internet. But it did not get the data from my own Web API. I was trying to use Typescript/Angular's HttpClient to get observables of my data.

However, I learned that Google Chrome has a console that shows error messages and when I was instructed to look there, I found the message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5112/qnas' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Why can't it get the data? ...

Comment: If you're going to self-answer, then the question needs more context. What error messages were there for example? Just saying "it doesn't work" gets your questions closed very quickly. Secondly, I think once you show the error message, this gets closed as a duplicate anyway.

Comment: @DavidG Better?

Comment: Not entirely, you haven't mentioned any error messages. You would have seen them in the browser console. Something telling you it is a CORS problem. But like I said, that would almost certainly make you end up on a question that already has an answer.

Comment: @DavidG Went back and created the problem and looked for the Google Console. Thanks for the suggestion. Where were you yesterday when I was struggling to find anything? :)

Comment: All my searching on StackOverflow yesterday did not produce the link that I shared below, so something is missing in the existing questions that did not point me to it.

Comment: But did you search for the error message from the console?

Comment: @DavidG Like I said, I did not know there was a Google Chrome Console. So now I am including that to help some one as well.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this must have qualified as a "Cross-Origin Request" to the ASP.NET Core Web API. As soon as I applied the code in this link to the Web API in Program.cs, it began shipping the data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(
      "Any",
      cors =>
      {
          cors.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
      });
});
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors("Any");
```